# Div with padding with child div at 100% width

Tags: html, css, less

I have a grid with 3 columns in which the divs all have `width: 33.333334%` and `padding 0 10px`.

Then inside of that I have a div for the content that is `position: absolute` to stick to the bottom of this div and it needs to be `width: 100%` relative to the grid div without the padding.

Example HTML

```
<div class="grid-item">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="grid-item-content"></div>
    </a>        
</div>
```

And the CSS / LESS

```
.grid-item {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 0 10px;

  a {
    display: block;
  }

  .grid-item-content {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

I've tried `Calc(100% - 20px)` but that is subtracting 20% instead of pixels.

Also found `box-sizing: padding-box;` which is unsupported in all browsers except for Firefox, so that didn't help either.

I'm also using LESS so any "LESS only" solution will work just fine.

Comment: Firstly, your title for the question is terrible, you should name it something useful to other people searching for questions. Also, your `grid-item` columns will add up to more than 100% I believe as the padding gets added to the width. However, to answer your question, I think if you make the item `position: relative` then the inner content div should be the correct size.

Comment: @Klors I changed the Title although I'm having a hard time coming up with a good title for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="grid-item">
<div class='s'>
    <div class="grid-item-content">text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-item {
   position:relative;
   width:33%;
   padding: 0 10px;
   }
.grid-item .s{
   position:relative;
   padding:0 10px;
   }
.grid-item-content {
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/HzZW7/

Comment: Adding a relative block in between did fix the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Unlike `padding-box`, `border-box` has better browser support.

Comment: @R4VANG3R Then you don't need `padding-box`. `border-box` behaves like `padding-box` if there is no border. So it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If `grid-item-content` is the only child of the `grid-item` div, then just remove the padding. From the code you've posted there doesn't seem to be a reason for it. If you have other items in that div that need to be inset away from the edge, give them a margin instead.

Comment: I also said it's example HTML.
It's a grid so there needs to be padding or margin otherwise they'll be stuck together.

Comment: To separate parent divs to fit the grid you ought to be using margins anyway - that's what they're for. Padding is for insets, which is causing your problem.

Comment: Total width = width + padding + margin + border so it wouldn't make a difference.